# Hibernate Criteria fails to find results when apostrophe is present

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

### Problem in short:

Hibernate criteria.list fails to find objects when query contains apostrophe **'**

### Long Version:

Hibernate: 3.2.7.ga

When users register, they are saved in the db with the following hibernate call:

```
 User user;
 //set data in user
 getHibernateTemplate().save(user);
```

This, as expected, takes care of properly handling special characters like the apostrophe **'**.

But when i go to retrieve the user with the following code, it fails to find users which registered with an apostrophe in their username:

```
public User getUserByUsername(String username) {
    Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("loginid", username));
    List<Utente> users = criteria.list();
    User user = null;
    if (!users.isEmpty()) {
        user = users.get(0);
    }
    return user;
}
```

The code works with *normal* usernames such as "test" but when giving a username like "test'test" criteria.list will return an empty list.
I checked and I know the user gets saved on the db, it simply cannot retrieve it with this code.

Any ideas?

### More info

Criteria list actually runs this code (removed some fields for clarity):

```
select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.loginid as loginid0_0_, this_.password as password0_0_, this_.email as email0_0_ from user this_ where this_.loginid=?
```

The loginid is a String in Java, a character varying(255) in SQL code.
Mapped as:

```
<property
    name="loginid"
    type="java.lang.String"
    column="loginid"
    not-null="true"
    unique="true"
 />
```

#### Misc info:

- **Database**: Postgres SQL 9.3
- **hibernate.dialect** = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
- **dataSource class**: "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"

Comment: what type is "loginid"?

Comment: String in java, character varying(255) in SQL

Comment: The database is Postgres 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEBAK... the login form was set to truncate the user login to a shorter amount of characters than the registration form - coincidence was that the string i tested with the apostrophe was also very long. Simply put the problem was due to an incorrect username used for the criteria.